# How to show id in Resource Routes url?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, routes, inertiajs

**Update:**

This line of code in the frontend was the culprit:

```
<inertia-link v-if="options.edit" :href="'/admin/gallery/edit/1'">
```

I had to change it to:

```
<inertia-link v-if="options.edit" :href="'/admin/gallery/1/edit'">
```

to make it comply with the [laravel resource format](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller) for `edit`, provided by @Babak.

**Original Post:**

How would I transform this route in **`web.php`**:

```
Route::get('/admin/gallery/edit/{id}', function ($id) {
    $data = Gallery::find($id);
    return inertia('backend/cms-gallery-edit', ['data' => $data]);
});
```

to a resource route with its resource controller function:

```
Route::resource('/admin/gallery', GalleryController::class);
```

**`GalleryController.php`**:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $data = Gallery::find($id);
    // assign id to end of route
    return inertia('backend/cms-gallery-edit', ['data' => $data]);
}
```

**Edit**:

I've tried both approaches of @Babak's answer, which work for `index` and `create` routes but the `edit` route still throws a `404`. It is the only route encompassing an `id`.

**`web.php`**:

```
Route::resource('/admin/gallery', GalleryController::class)->only('index', 'create', 'edit');
```

**`GalleryController.php`**:

```
public function edit($gallery)
{
    $data = Gallery::find($gallery);
    return inertia('backend/cms-gallery-edit', ['data' => $data]);
}
```

Inertia passes the `id` from the frontend via href:

```
<inertia-link v-if="options.edit" :href="'/admin/gallery/edit/1'">
```

Browser shows:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/gallery/edit/1 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fixed structure for laravel resource route method, you can see full list [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller). For edit page, it will generate something like `'/admin/gallery/{gallery}/edit'`

You can write it like below:

In your `web.php` file:

```php
Route::resource('/admin/gallery', GalleryController::class)->only('edit');
```

And in your controller, name of the resource must be the same as your function's parameter.

```php
public function edit($gallery)
{
    $data = Gallery::find($gallery);
    // assign id to end of route
    return inertia('backend/cms-gallery-edit', ['data' => $data]);
}
```

Or, you can customize it using `parameter` method. Refer to [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters)

```php
Route::resource('/admin/gallery', GalleryController::class)->only('edit')->parameters([
    'gallery' => 'id'
]);
```

And your controller

```php
public function edit($id)
{
    $data = Gallery::find($id);
    // assign id to end of route
    return inertia('backend/cms-gallery-edit', ['data' => $data]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick and extensive answer. Do I understand it correctly that if I use `->only`, it transforms the resource route into a `single route`, so I will have to create one for each resource function?

Comment: No, you can pass multiple parameters to `only()` method. For example, if you want to generate a route for edit page and a route for update using `PUT/PATCH` methods, you can pass two parameters such as `only('edit', 'update')`

Comment: I've tried both approaches but neither does work for the `edit` method. I've added it to the question.

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov you should use **edit** after the **id**, something like `/admin/gallery/1/edit` not `/admin/gallery/edit/1`

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I didn't have to do anything except change the inertia route in the frontend. Thank you